# Check if DAYOFWEEK() Exists between a date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables

```
Specialoffer
 Id (int)
 ValidFrom (date)
 ValidTo (date)

SpecialOfferExcludedDays
 Id  (int) (ForeignKey with Table1.Id)
 DayId (int)

Days
 DayId (int) (ForeignKey with Table3.DayId)
 Name (text)
```

Specialoffer contains

```
'1', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-14'

'2', '2013-02-01', '2013-02-05'

'3', '2013-11-21', '2013-11-25'
```

SpecialOfferExcludedDays contains

```
'3', '4'
```

Days contains

```
'1', 'Sunday'
'2', 'Monday'
'3', 'Tuesday'
'4', 'Wednesday'
'5', 'Thursday'
'6', 'Friday'
'7', 'Saturday'
```

I'm trying to write a query to achieve the following;

- Get All Ids from the SpecialOffers table, between the given date range of ValidFrom and ValidTo
- Exclude any records from SpecialOffers  if a Day (e.g Tuesday) exists in SpecialOfferExcludedDays  for the given Id.  It is not limited to 1 day.  For example a Id could be excluded for Monday and Saturday

My query looks something like the following at the moment with no logic for the Days

```
SELECT Id
FROM SpecialOffers 
WHERE (ValidFrom > '2013-11-25'
AND ValidTo < '2013-11-30')
```

So for example I'm making a order today for a hotel reservation, for the night of 1st Dec 2013.  Give me all the possible special offers, that are valid for the 1st Dec.  Taking into consideration any Special Offers that are not valid on certain days

**EDIT**

A sample deal might get all Ids where the stay is between 1st Dec and 25th December excluding Fridays and Saturdays.

Is this possible to do ?  Or would I be better writing this logic in my C# app.

Comment: Could you give some more data and your expected results?

Comment: I've added some additional data

Comment: @Tommo1977 why store day of week? It's definitely can be extracted from your date. No?

Comment: @AlmaDo I'm storing Day of the week, so the user can restrict what Ids are returned if the Day exists between the date range

Comment: Let's say table 1 has a range of 01/01/2013 - 01/31/2013 and that table 2 only has an entry for Tuesday.  Are you saying you want to exclude record 1 in its entirety because there are Tuesdays or are you wanting a list of all dates between 01/01 and 01/31 that are not Tuesdays?

Comment: @dazedandconfused Correct, I don't want to return any Id if we find a matching day in Table2.  For example a Id could be excluded for Monday and Saturday.

Comment: I've added more context to the question

Comment: There are so many edge conditions that aren't being discussed here that have a direct impact on the design.  For example, as you've explained it, if 5 days of a 6 day reservation are eligible for a special offer the entire stay is excluded... is that intentional?  What if a reservation crosses the boundary between the end of special offer 1 and the beginning of special offer 2?

Comment: The dates to and from have to match the whole period, it can't cross any boundaries.  So if it doesn't match, the deal is excluded. I'll add a example deal description to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. This will give you all rows in table 1 that meet your datefrom and two criteria except any rows that are associated with a Tuesday record in table 3 (via the table2 many-many join).

```
SELECT Id
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE (ValidFrom > '2013-11-25'
AND ValidTo < '2013-11-30')
and not exists
(select 1 from table2 t2
inner join table3 t3 on t2.DayID=t3.dayID
where t1.ID=t2.ID and t3.Name='Tuesday')
```

Regarding whether to do it in c# instead, no one can answer that for you without knowing more about the structure of your app and the size of the datasets (among other items).

EDIT: here's an answer to what I believe is the updated version of what you want, knowing what offers are available for any given day:

```
DECLARE @dateIwanttocheck datetime='1/1/2013'
SELECT Id FROM Specialoffer t1 
WHERE @dateIwanttocheck between ValidFrom and ValidTo 
and not exists (select 1 from SpecialOfferExcludedDays t2 
inner join Days t3 on t2.DayID=t3.dayID 
where t1.ID=t2.ID and datepart(dw,@dateIwanttocheck)=t3.DayID)
```

Comment: I've added more context to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I've added to the question to reflect a stay at a hotel.  I should of included this initially.

Comment: I see you've clarified your question. So you want to know for any give date, what special offers are available? What's confusing about trying to answer is that your query has a RANGE of dates hardcode as opposed to a single date. If it's a single day, I would do this:


 ` DECLARE @dateIwanttocheck datetime='1/1/2013' SELECT Id FROM Specialoffer t1 WHERE @dateIwanttocheck between ValidFrom and ValidTo and not exists (select 1 from SpecialOfferExcludedDays t2 inner join Days t3 on t2.DayID=t3.dayID where t1.ID=t2.ID and datepart(dw,@dateIwanttocheck)=t3.DayID)`

Comment: apologize for the bad formatting above, unsure how to do it in a comment

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will do what you are looking for:

Using your data, this selects Special Offer 3, because, you are looking for Thursday, and the offer is valid on Thursdays.

```
SELECT distinct so.Id
FROM SpecialOffer so
LEFT JOIN SpecialOfferExcludeDays soed on so.id = soed.id and soed.dayId in (5)
WHERE ValidFrom > '2013-11-20'
AND ValidTo < '2013-11-30'
AND soed.id is null;
```

Using your data, this doesn't Special Offer 3, because, you are looking for Wednesday, and the offer is not valid on Wednesdays.

```
SELECT distinct so.Id
FROM SpecialOffer so
LEFT JOIN SpecialOfferExcludeDays soed on so.id = soed.id and soed.dayId in (4)
WHERE ValidFrom > '2013-11-20'
AND ValidTo < '2013-11-30'
AND soed.id is null;
```

I've added the "distinct" in here, just in case SpecialOfferExcludedDays has multiple blackout days for the same SpecialOffer.  Otherwise you would get multiple IDs in this case.

[Link to SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b794/19)

From the feedback, I'm thinking that maybe you just want a group_concat, which would list all the excluded days.  You could then use the application to change the display.  For example:

```
SELECT so.Id, group_concat(days.name) as excludedDayNames, 
  group_concat(days.dayId) as excludedDayIds
FROM SpecialOffer so
LEFT JOIN SpecialOfferExcludeDays soed on so.id = soed.id
LEFT JOIN days on soed.dayId = days.dayId
WHERE ValidFrom > '2013-11-20'
AND ValidTo < '2013-11-30'
group by so.id;
```

[Link to SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b794/19)

Comment: Rather than hard code the part soed.dayId in (5), I'd like to be able to make this check for all days between the date range of 2013-11-20 and 2013-11-30